# Looping in the GUI

Tags: wxpython, python-multithreading

I have a panel in wxPython where I want to take a button `enable monitor` and when clicked start a loop of the below, but also free up the GUI again and thusly update the button label to `disable monitor`.  Once `disable` is clicked, it would stop the loop entirely.

I've looked at `threading`, but I am not sure that is what I should be doing in this case?

The entire loop runs within a `def startStop(self)` declaration and is run within the wxPanel's `class`.

I'm in way over my head, but I've been tinkering with this GUI for a while now and would love to round out this lesson with doing it the right way. :)

Pseudo code:

```
 while zonesToMonitor != []: 
        time.sleep(int(self.tc_CheckInterval.Value))

        j = 0
        for i in zonesToMonitor:
            maxVOL = maxVolPerZone[j]

            urllib.urlopen("http://" + ip_address + ":" + self.tc_serverPort.Value +"/data/rendererData?data=R::" + wx.FindWindowByLabel(i).Label).read()

            INFO = urllib.urlopen("http://" + ip_address + ":" + self.tc_serverPort.Value +"/data/rendererAction?data=class").read()

            curTime = datetime.datetime.now()
            curTime = curTime.strftime("%H:%M")

            if self.ck_QuietHours.Value == True:
                quietStartHr = self.tc_quietHr.Value
                quietEndHr = self.tc_quietHrStop.Value
                quietVol = self.tc_QuietVol.Value
                if (curTime > quietStartHr) and (curTime < quietEndHr):
                    print "In quiet hours..."
                    maxVOL = quietVol            

            if self.ck_MuteHours.Value == True:
                muteStartHr = self.tc_MuteHr.Value
                muteEndHr = self.tc_MuteHrStop.Value                   
                if (curTime > muteStartHr) and (curTime < muteEndHr):
                    print "In mute time..."
                    maxVOL = 0

            OUTPUT = re.findall('(?<=VOLUME::).*?(?=_\|_)', INFO)

            if maxVOL == '':
                maxVOL = 0

            if OUTPUT == '':
                OUTPUT = 0

            OUTPUT = map(int, OUTPUT)             

            if OUTPUT > int(maxVOL):
                url = "http://" + ip_address + ":" + self.tc_serverPort.Value + "/data/rendererAction?data=VOLUME::" + str(maxVOL)
                urllib.urlopen(url).read()

            j += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think its a bad choice at all to implement this kind of task with Threads, you can read more about threads and wxpython here: [Non-Blocking Gui](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui), and also here: [LongRunningTasks](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) where the author discusses the alternatives to threading with wxpython.

it can be done in the following way:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ToKill = False
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.FooHandler()
            if self.ToKill:
                return None
    def FooHandler(self):
        """ your function here """
        print 3

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=-1, style=wx.RAISED_BORDER)
        Bsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        button=wx.ToggleButton(self, label="Click To Enable")

        Bsizer.Add(button,1,wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(Bsizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON,self.buttonEvt,id=button.GetId())

    def buttonEvt(self, evt):
        clickedToggleButton = evt.GetEventObject()
        if clickedToggleButton.GetValue():
            self.thread = MyThread()
            self.thread.start()
            clickedToggleButton.SetLabel("Click To Disable")
        else:
            self.thread.ToKill = True
            clickedToggleButton.SetLabel("Click To Enable")
```

Comment: Wow -- thank you -- I finally, FINALLY, understand how to make this work after countless hours of ripping sample code off the internet.  Thanks for keeping it simple. :)